# Добрый вечер, не знаю, задают ли здесь вопросы по вебу, но тем не менее

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка, flexbox, веб-дизайн

У меня есть шаблон:

[image: шаблон]

И мне нужно **с помощью флекса** подогнать бэкграунд кнопки с текстом 'Как это работает?', сделать справа и слева чуть меньше и немного поднять его снизу и сверху, я пытался делать с помощью отступов, но это не сработало, вот код:

```
.how {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 480px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Вот так выглядит кнопка в шаблоне:

[image: кнопка]

Как её можно повторить? (Я не знаю как это сделать)

Comment: `если нужно прикреплю код`

Comment: окей, секунду!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна структура вашего html, но в целом вы не туда добавляете flex

Можно сделать например так:
Отступы внутри кнопки задаете через padding, а выравнивание кнопки и текста флексом выполняете от общего контейнера

```css
.flex__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex__link {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
background-color: #c7c7c7;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__container"><h1> Я робот юрист</h1>
<a class="flex__link" href=""> Как это работает?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но появились другие проблемки, мне нужно, чтобы слева и справа кнопка была поменьше как на оригинальном шаблоне в фигме

Comment: сейчас минутку!

Comment: @жабаклава добро пожаловать на "Stack Overflow на русском"! Не стоит изменять суть вопроса, если на него уже существуют ответ, вместо этого [создайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) со скорректированным содержимым, а этот вопрос откатите к оригинальной версии.

Comment: Касательно размера кнопки:
Добавьте в .flex__link свойство width: 250px с нужным вам размером и уберите свойство padding
Самым простым способом добавить иконку в кнопку в вашем случае будет тег img прикрепил демо, только учитывайте ваши данные из макета https://codepen.io/orloviss/pen/qByrxeM